# How do I use a filter within a mutate statement?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to calculate the investment associated with a list of companies by a particular date. I have the list of companies along with the date for investments.

This is my data-

reference dates

```
d1 <- as.Date(paste0("201001","01"), "%Y%m%d")
d2 <- as.Date(paste0("201201","01"), "%Y%m%d")
dat <- seq(d1,d2,by="month")
```

investment data

```
> head(df)
        company_name funding_round_type funding_round_code  funded_at raised_amount_usd  yearMonth
1            0-6.com            venture                  A 2008-03-19           2000000 2008-03-01
2   004 Technologies            venture                    2014-07-24                NA 2014-03-01
3 01Games Technology        undisclosed                    2014-07-01             41250 2014-03-01
4             H2O.ai            venture                  B 2015-11-09          20000000 2015-03-01
5             H2O.ai               seed                    2013-05-22           3000000 2013-03-01
6             H2O.ai            venture                    2013-01-03           1700000 2013-03-01
```

> I'd like to calculate how much each company had raised by the time of each of the dates in `dat`.

```
result <- merge(dat, df$company_name) %>% 
  mutate(asOf = x,
         companyName = as.character(y)) %>% select(-x, -y) %>%
  mutate(raised = sum(df[df$company_name == companyName & 
                                      df$yearMonth < asOf,c("raised_amount_usd")]))
```

Unfortunately, the filter isn't working. If I set it to a particular company it works. This works, for example: `sum(df[df$company_name == companyName & df$yearMonth < asOf,c("raised_amount_usd")])`.

I'd like to get a result that looks like this -

```
        asOf                      companyName            cumulative_raised
1            2010-01-01            0-6.com                  0
2            2010-02-01            0-6.com                  12000000
3            2010-03-01            0-6.com                  12000000
4            2010-01-01            H2O.ai                   0
5            2010-02-01            H2O.ai                   5000000
6            2010-03-01            H2O.ai                   9300000
```

How do I get the filter to work when it's in a mutate clause?

Comment: Please describe the problem not the solution. This makes it misleading, what exactly do you want to do? See [the X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). `filter` might be interpreted as referring to the `filter` function.

Comment: Sure, I updated it with that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is using `complete` (from `tidyr`) with `group_by`, `mutate`, and `summarize` (from `dplyr`) as well as `cumsum` and not `sum` (base `R`). 
As the data you provide is barely overlapping with the interval you desire, I modified the interval a bit to show how it works. Of course this is totally flexible and you can use whatever interval you want to have:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my.dat <- seq(as.Date("2013-03-01"), as.Date("2014-04-01"), by = "month")

new.df <- my.df %>% 
  complete(company_name, yearMonth = my.dat, fill = list(raised_amount_usd = 0)) %>% 
  group_by(company_name, yearMonth) %>% 
  summarize(raised_amount_usd = sum(raised_amount_usd, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  arrange(yearMonth) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative_raised = cumsum(raised_amount_usd)) %>% 
  select(company_name, yearMonth, cumulative_raised) 

tail(new.df, 10)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   company_name [4]
   company_name       yearMonth  cumulative_raised
   <chr>              <date>                 <dbl>
 1 01Games Technology 2014-02-01                 0
 2 H2O.ai             2014-02-01           4700000
 3 0-6.com            2014-03-01                 0
 4 004 Technologies   2014-03-01                 0
 5 01Games Technology 2014-03-01             41250
 6 H2O.ai             2014-03-01           4700000
 7 0-6.com            2014-04-01                 0
 8 004 Technologies   2014-04-01                 0
 9 01Games Technology 2014-04-01             41250
10 H2O.ai             2014-04-01           4700000
```

**How does it work?**

First, with `complete` we fill in the missing dates in the `yearMonth` column and exclude those not within the specified time range. Then with the `group_by` we form groups of `company_name` and `yearMonth` and then `summarize` the `raised_amount_usd` for each date and company (to add up amount that was raised at the same date as for H2O.ai at 2013-03-01). Then we arrange the data by `yearMonth` and calculate the cumulative sum. The data is still grouped by `company_name` and thus the cumulative sum per company is calculated. Finally, we only select those columns you were interested in.

**Data**

```
my.df <- 
  structure(list(company_name = c("0-6.com", "004 Technologies", "01Games Technology", "H2O.ai", "H2O.ai", "H2O.ai"), 
                 funding_round_type = c("venture", "venture", "undisclosed", "venture", "seed", "venture"), 
                 funding_round_code = c("A", " ", " ", "B", " ", " "), 
                 funded_at = structure(c(13957, 16275, 16252, 16748, 15847, 15708), class = "Date"), 
                 raised_amount_usd = c(2000000L, NA, 41250L, 20000000L, 3000000L, 1700000L), 
                 yearMonth = structure(c(13939, 16130, 16130, 16495, 15765, 15765), class = "Date")), 
            class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This does the trick. Thanks kath. Do you have any insight into why companyName didn't work as a filter?